# How to handle error conditions of pthread_mutex_destroy

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, mutex

When I try to destroy mutex via pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex), it intermittently fails.

I am doing an assert if the pthread_mutex_destroy fails. But do we have a better option compared to assert (apart from raising exception)?

EDIT:

```
void cleanUp()
{
  int rval=0;
  rval = pthread_cond_destroy(&m_Condition);
  assert(rval == 0);
  rval = pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_Mutex);
  assert(rval == 0);
  rval = pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&m_Attr);
  assert(rval == 0);
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
void semaphoreVMware::semaphoreVMware()
{
int rval = 0;
rval = pthread_mutexattr_init(&m_Attr);
assert(rval == 0);
rval = pthread_mutexattr_settype(&m_Attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
assert(rval == 0);
rval = pthread_mutex_init(&m_Mutex, &m_Attr);
assert(rval == 0);
rval = pthread_cond_init(&m_Condition, NULL);
assert(rval == 0);
}
```

EDIT 3:Declaration of the mutex:

```
env::Mutex m_Mutex;
```

Comment: do you know why it is failing?

Comment: Can you please post some sample code? Can't you check the return value and take an action instead of throwing an assert?

Comment: @ServerMonkey almost all of the errors from pthread_mutex_destroy are programming errors, with the exception of resource limitation, which should not be intermittent.  It would be better to fix the problems so that the errors do not occur.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your reply.Actually the cleanup code which i have posted gets called whenever we stop our service.The scenario is starting and stopping of the service and this we doing in a loop.When we do these iteration,pthread_mutex_destroy() returns non-zero value very intermittently and hence assert hits and then aborts the program and coredumps.This abortion is irregular.

Comment: What happens if you simply don't call cleanUp() at all?  If the mutex/s are used only inside your service, there should be no problem in the OS cleaning them up as your service process terminates.

Comment: Beware of premature stoptimization..

Comment: You should **really** add error checking and logging to the pthread calls. This would at least shed light on what is happening and you do **not** need to dig around in the dark, guessing what might have happend ...

Answer (score 4):

According to man pthread_mutex_destroy there is only one error that can occur. That is that at destruction time the mutex is still locked. Thus you probably don't unlock your mutex before trying to destroy/free it.

from `man 3 pthread_mutex_destroy`:

```
   The pthread_mutex_destroy function returns the following error code on error:

          EBUSY  the mutex is currently locked.
```

If you destroy the mutex you should check whether the return value is `EBUSY` (you might have to `#include <errno.h>`).

So what you do now is you have `void cleanUp()` you could make it return an `int` and try again when `pthread_mutex_destroy` fails. however you do have three functions that can fail in one function, thus in this case it might be wiser to break the function to different parts.

**edit**
What I'm telling above can help one to the question you orininally asked. But after quite some comments on this answere there is more than meets the eye. It seems you are mixing the Pthreads API with C++ style mutex systems. Because you are mixing them you get in troubles. Stick to either the C++ mutex/thread API or the pthread api, probably your C++ API is a wrapper around the pthread API, and therefore you'll get very strange results.

Comment: Tis issue is typical of the messes that multithreaded devs. get into when trying to shut down complex, multithreaded code in a 'clean' manner.  On many OS, it's better to not try.

Comment: @MartinJames An other issue is that it seems that the OP puts the mutexes on the stack, not allocating them dynamically. But he doesn't show that part of the code.

Comment: @MartinJames: Besides I feel not to do a "clean" shutdown is bad advice, I wonder what the OS has got to do with this?

Comment: @alk - it's bad advice on some of the more primitive OS that posix may run on. On others, the cost of attempting a 'clean' shutdown, both in terms of time, CPU-use, bugs in avoidable shutdown-code like this appears to be, extra testing of shutdown code etc. is very high.  A complex, multithreaded app is very difficult to shut down cleanly unless you are an OS - user code does not have the tools to always do it reliably.  Sometimes, you have to pay the high cost of clean shutdowns, but I try very hard to not pay it if I can avoid it.

Comment: I have added the code for mutex initializiation and setting its type.I tried adding the pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex) before destroying the mutex but even after doing this pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex) intermittently fails.

Comment: You can't unlock it if some other thread holds the lock.  Go on, bite the bullet.. comment out the calls.  Feel the freedom :)

Comment: @Ravikanth: As the mutex seems to be a recursive one, unlocking it once might not be enough.

Comment: @Ravikanth please also show how the Mutexes are declared, since I think you use automatic memory (you don't create them using malloc, calloc etc.) In that case they will automatically be destroyed when they go out of scope. And do I see member functions in C code, this seems unlikely.

Comment: @alk:So Can you point me as of how to unlock the recursive mutex correctly?

Comment: @MartinJames: As per my knowledge,when we destroy mutex resources held up will be freed or will be corrupted.So,even if i fire assert when mutex is not destroyed,that's gonna just abort the execution right?So commenting out the assert will realy be helpful?

Comment: @Ravikanth Are you sure that is a mutex from the pthread API? Anyway the declaration suggests, you use automatic memory (stack allocation), when the mutex goes out of scope it should be freed automatically.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Memory explicitly dynamically allocated (via `malloc/calloc/realloc/strdup` is never `free()`ed automagically not in C nor in C++!

Comment: @Ravikanth: Call `pthread_mutex_unlock()` as often on the mutex until an error is returned. You will add error checking to all the pthread calls anyway, won't you?

Comment: @alk your right, but I didn't say that, did I? I said after edit 3, which suggests the mutexes are not dynamically created, but automatically. Instances created in automatic memory, have their destructors called when they go out of scope. And I mostly agree with you that one should carefully look at error condtions after failed call in the posix api!

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Yes, you didn't say that. Sry, I misread your comment. However, `pthread_mutex_t` is not a class, so there is no destructor that can be called. To free resources associated with it one **needs to explicitly call** `pthread_mutex_destroy()`. Same for `pthread_cond_t`.

Comment: @MartinJames: "*A complex, multithreaded app is very difficult to shut down cleanly ...*" this a desgin-issue, isn't it?

Comment: @alk What about `pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`? If one call would call `pthread_mutex_destroy (&m);` as the OP does you are in trouble I think. But my answer is correct (I think) to the question asked.

Comment: So,as the mutex is recursive,destroying it until and unless the method pthread_mutex_destroy would be blocking call or else it should resolve the issue?

Comment: @alk yes, in that it's often either difficult, or actually impossible, to shut down an app cleanly.  Example - one thread has called a library function to invert a matrix, and it takes 30 seconds to return, how are you going to perform a clean shutdown in any reasonable time?

Comment: @MartinJames: Add cancellation points to the inversion function, apply/push clean-up handlers prior to calling it and then cancel the thread from outside.

Comment: @Ravikanth: Not "*destroying it until ...*" but **unlocking it until** unlocking would fail. Please read my previous comment on this carefully.

Comment: @alk:So unlocking it until it gets unlocked will not be a blocking call?

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Your example is perfectly valid and would cause no issues.

Comment: @Ravikanth: In any case the thread that locked the mutex also needs to unlock the mutex. For recursive mutexes this could be necessary more then once.

Comment: @alk:Thanks alk.I am trying it out and will let you know the results.Thanks a lot for your continous help.

Comment: @Ravikanth Are you sure the mutex is actually a `pthread_mutex_t` you seem to be mixing C++ and C. Since C++ std::Mutex in C++11 might be a wrapper around phtread_mutex_t, you are in trouble if you start mixing them.

Comment: Dxxn, I missed "Edit 3" ... - *sigh* @hetepeperfan

Comment: @alk ;-) I allready mentionned about this a few comments ago:)

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Man sees, what he wants so see ... - I actually didn't miss the Edit but its content. -oo-

Comment: @Ravikanth I made an extra edit, which addresses another problem at hand. But since this is the thirty-something comment on my answer, I hope my edit make a bit sense to you. This also demonstrates why it is import to show ALL relevant code when posting on stackoverflow.